# dbunit dataset does not put boolean field into db

Tags: java, integration-testing, dbunit

I use DbUnit for integration tests. I have the following dataset.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="dataset.xsd">
    <USERS ID="1" EMAIL="" LASTNAME="A" LASTMODIFIED="2001-01-01 00:00:00.0" />
    <USERS ID="2" EMAIL="" LASTNAME="D" LASTMODIFIED="2001-01-01 00:00:00.0" ACTIVE="true" />
</dataset>
```

Somehow the boolean field ACTIVE is not set on the second User when I load it from DB in my test.

The test looks like this:

```
@SpringApplicationContext("component-context-test-dao.xml")
@DataSet
public class UserDaoImplIT extends UnitilsJUnit4 {

@SpringBeanByType
private UserDaoImpl userDao;

@Test
public void shouldReturnTrueIfFoundActiveUserWithEmail() throws InterruptedException {
    boolean exits = userDao.isEmailFromActiveUserInUsers("anEmailThatDoesNotExist@oeamtc.at");
    List list = HibernateUnitils.getSession().createQuery("from User").list();
    assertThat(exits, is(true));

}
}
```

I run the test from within eclipse against an in-memory h2.

Any ideas why all fields are mapped except the boolean one?

Answer (score 1):

Because the value should be `TRUE` or `FALSE`

[Datatypes - boolean type](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#boolean_type)